Elf Left In the Humans' World, Came Back To A Magical Farm
I believe there were four or five books in the series, maybe more or less. I remember the protagonist being female. I read this approximately three years ago, and I think it was relatively new then, but maybe not. The cover art seemed more modern to me. I don't remember any of the names in the story.
I believe that the story went something along the lines of an elf baby was left in the human world, was adopted, and then, due to some sort of magical fire, I believe, was discovered and led back to the elf realm.
I remember that she was taken in by a couple who owned a magical beast ranch, and the protagonist had to attend some sort of magic school. I vividly remember that the protagonist didn't really ever "power up" to defeat the bad guys in the first one or two books, and that it made me kind of mad. I believe she got a lot more powerful towards the later books.
If there is anything you think I should add to help the search, feel no hesitation to tell me.

After hours of searching and scouring my memories, I finally found what I was looking for. The Book is Keeper Of the Lost Cities by Shannon Messenger. Remembering that it was elves and not fairies was the main breakthrough, because I kept getting directed to the Fablehaven series, which was not it. Thank you DavidW for helping me out, and I hope this helps anyone else who doesn't remember this series.

The protagonist of the series, Sophie, is a twelve-year-old elf with telepathy who lives in San Diego, California with a human family.
While on a school field trip, another elf teenager, Fitz tracks her down and reveals that she is a elf. He discusses the reality of their world with Sophie and tells her that she must move to the Lost Cities, a place unknown to humankind where elves, trolls, ogres, goblins, gnomes and dwarves live in harmony. She is forced to leave her human family behind and stay with an elvin couple, Grady and Edaline, who later adopt her. She starts school at a noble elvin academy named Foxfire.

